# How to Get The Path Of the Downloaded Pdf file From System Using Winform Application

Tags: c#, .net

I am Creating windows App there  I am Downloading pdf file those files are stored into every system Downloaded  path are(their Specific path Where they are saving So I have to Show the path to User Where the File got Downloaded using Winform So How can  i get those path please help me.

Reply as early as possible
Thank you

Comment: Show your download code.. It must be including the save path :)

Comment: "Reply as early as possible" - sorry, but provide your code as early as possible to get help

Comment: Thanks sami  but the path is virtual in windows app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with your broken English, vagueness, and lack of code example. My best guess is that you're trying to identify the users "Downloads" directory?

Here's how I'd go about it (given this is what you mean):

```
// Identify the users "user" directory
string userPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
DirectoryInfo user = new DirectoryInfo(userPath);
if (user.Exists)
{
    // Identify the "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" directory on Windows Vista, 7, 8 systems.
    DirectoryInfo downloads = new DirectoryInfo(user + @"\Downloads");
    if (downloads.Exists)
    {
        // return the full path "C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads"
        return downloads.FullName;
    }
    else
    {
        // Couldn't find it, maybe they're on Windows XP
        string xpDocs = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        DirectoryInfo xpDownloads = new DirectoryInfo(xpDocs + @"\Downloads");
        if (xpDownloads.Exists)
        {
            // return the full path "C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\My Documents\Downloads"
            return xpDownloads.FullName;
        }
        else
        {
            // Couldn't identify a "Downloads" directory in either location
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Cannot identify the users 'Downloads' directory.");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // Couldn't identify a "%USERPROFILE%" folder. Shouldn't ever happen...
    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Cannot identify the users default directory.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you For Response  in Hurry I have Posted Like That .it was solved for me.